# Actions and http post request for redirection and perist

Tags: php, http, servlets, http-post, http-proxy

I'm in a bit of a struggle. I'm having an order form which should send data to an external link and redirects the user to this certain link. But i also need to send this certain data to my personal servlet to persist the data into my database. 
So my first idea was to send the data to my servlet send an http post request with the data to the external link and return a view with a form action to the external link (as a redirect).
But thats not working because I'm having to posts to the external link.
After some research i found out that for this approach my servlet has to work as an http proxy (not sure if thats truly true) but I dont know how.

So I want to know if its possible to send 2 post request:

- 1 to my servlet
- 1 to the external link

and also redirect the user from my page to the external link. doesn't matter if its with php, java, perl what ever. Just need a solution :)
thx for any help.

Comment: Let me guess: payment system. If so - then use their API to create reversal to your site. That will be - 0. Save data to your DB (your side, your application); 1. Redirect user to external page; 2. Get data from reversal according to external API

Comment: yeah kind. but i want to do it my way. any possibility to do that ?